# For loop with Table name in Stored Procedures

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am working on Oracle stored procedures.

My requirement is below

```
IF variable1 := 'true"
THEN
    tableName=abr
ELSE
    tableName=mvr
END IF;

    FOR i IN (select unique(row1) as sc from tableName t where t.row2 = 'name') LOOP
     BEGIN
        -- required Logic
     END
    END LOOP;
```

But here I am not able to pass the table name in tableName parameter. How to do it?

Comment: what is row1 datatype?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use `Execute Immediate` - it's designed for operations that aren't known until run time.

For normal operations, Oracle must know the tables and columns at compile time.  You can't do `SELECT * FROM tableName` because it has no idea what tableName is and therefore it can't be compiled correctly.

Instead, you can do `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM ' || tableName;`

You can select your results `INTO` a variable, loop the result set, or `BULK COLLECT` into a structure and then iterate that.

For a simple select into, you can do this:

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM ' || tableName INTO V_COL1, V_COL2`

V_COL1 & V_COL2 are just local variables, tableName is a string representing your table name, and COL2 and COL2 are columns in the table you're selecting from.  You can use the likes of ALL_TAB_COLUMNS to get the structure of a table dynamically.

Here is an example from Oracle docs:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE query_invoice(
       month VARCHAR2, 
       year VARCHAR2) IS
    TYPE cur_typ IS REF CURSOR;
    c cur_typ;
    query_str VARCHAR2(200);
    inv_num NUMBER;
    inv_cust VARCHAR2(20);
    inv_amt NUMBER;
BEGIN
    query_str := 'SELECT num, cust, amt FROM inv_' || month ||'_'|| year 
      || ' WHERE invnum = :id';
    OPEN c FOR query_str USING inv_num;
    LOOP
        FETCH c INTO inv_num, inv_cust, inv_amt;
        EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
        -- process row here
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c;
END;
/
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_dy.htm

Answer (score -1):

You are going to have to build a for loop for each table then use your logic to determine which loop you will execute.

Comment: Hi , The loop is very big and if I repeat the loop then the code redundancy will be high.

Comment: Ok, then try placing your select as something like this:<br>`'select unique(row1) as sc from' || tableName || 'where...`